# How do I make square brackets without top/bottom feet

Tags: brackets

How do you create square brackets that don't have the top or bottom feet?  I'd like to use the symbol to define an operator for half-wave rectification.

thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a vertical bar (`|`) for brackets without any feet at all, `\lfloor`/`\rfloor` for the floor function (bottom feet only), or `\lceil`/`\rceil` for the ceiling function (no bottom feet, top feet only).

See p. 146 - 147 of the TeXbook for more information.